# copy text from dynamic webpage to a string

Tags: java, android, string, android-webview, copy-paste

website looks somewhat like this:
[dynamic webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMbj8.gif)

i need to copy all text from a dynamic webpage[keeps changeing for each second like there is a countdown/loading] for each second to a string

previously i tried this code,

```
private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {}

protected String doInBackground(String... address) {
String output = "";
try {
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(address[0]);
java.io.BufferedReader in = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
output += line;
}
in.close(); } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
output = e.getMessage();
} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
output = e.getMessage();
} catch (Exception e) {
output = e.toString();
}
return output;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {}

protected void onPostExecute(String s){
textview1.setText(s); }
```

it only gives source code of webpage
and it only works on static webpage

what that code gives me is :

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

but, what i need i need is just
`17:07:24`
i know Timer on Java.Utils

but what i need is just to copy all text from a webview/webpage and assign it to a string,
**like, go to a random webpage > SELECT ALL > COPY > and PASTE it on notepad** *[manually]*

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can render values on a webpage

Assign backend values to a JavaScript object or use expression language.

For reference go throw this link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language